# Javascript / CSS not working for IE 10 but working for IE 8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In my css I have this

```
#inner div {
    display: inline;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and in my html, I have this

```
<div id="inner">
    <h2> <span class="action">Click</span> on each button to read more about them </h2>
     <br />
     <span id="here"></span>    
</div>
```

And in my Javascript I have this

```
var divComposition = "<div id='div" + i + "'><p></p></div>";    
$('#here').after(divComposition);
```

So I'm placing it after the span, but it is still inside

```
#inner
```

so it is a

```
#inner div
```

. The problem is that in IE 8, it works. The divs are inline with the background color as black. However, in I.E 10, the divs are not inline and the background color is not balck. How come? I was thinking if I move the CSS below the Javascript then it will work but that doesn't work either. Any ideas on how to solve this? the I.E 10 developer tools shows no errors.

Comment: What div's should not appear on top of each other? The div you are creating appears after a <h2> and a <br>, so it SHOULD appear on the next line, whether inline or block.

Comment: @Gaurav whoops sorry the <br /> wasn't supposed to be there. I just edited my post and removed the <br />.. Also, even if the divs are supposed to appear on top of another, I still don't know why the black background isn't there.

Comment: Well IF I put some text in there, instead of just <p></p>, I see the black background.

Comment: The divs are size zero otherwise.

Comment: @Gaurav I have some more javascript code which basically takes words from an array and appends it inside the 'p'. I append it like this $('#div0 p').append(headings[0]).addClass('div0'); .. #div0 is the id of one of the divs and headings is an array and headings[0] is a word. When I open it up in IE 10, it is just a white page (since I made all the text color white. When I highlight the page, I can see the words. Which means the words are there, they are just white and on a white background when it should be a black background.

Comment: Well then post your entire code lol

Comment: @Gaurav the code is huge (plus is pretty messy), people would give me a downvote if I post the code lol. But okay I tried to actually type a word inside the <p>'s and it even after that, the divs still appears not inline without a black background.. you said that you put something inside the <p> and when you did, the divs were inline with a black background right? can you just confirm again that this was in IE 10? If yes, then I will run through my entire code again and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Elements styled

```
display:inline;
```

will ignore height and width, or should, anyway. Have you tried it with inline-block instead of inline?

Comment: If I make it inline-block then the divs appear one on top of another, so I left it at inline because I want then beside eachother.. I still don't know why IE 10 is ignoring the background color and display as well. In IE 8 it doesn't ignore the width and height even though my display is inline.

Comment: What is the positioning/styling of the er, outer div with the ID of inner?

Comment: @circleofconfusion wait, what do you mean "the er, outer div with the ID of inner"? you mean of the positioning and styling of the divs inside #inner?

Comment: @user2719875, no, I mean the actual styling of #inner itself. Its position and display may affect its child elements, especially if it's inline or inline-block itself.

Comment: @circleofconfusion okay so #inner { text-align: center;} and #inner div p {padding-top: 65px; color: white; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 6px;} and #inner h2 {font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;}

Comment: I added your styles to Gurav's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWh9W/4/), and it made no appreciable change. I definitely am seeing 4 black squares inline below the heading in IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks will make your `div` elements align vertically...

Change this line

```
var divComposition = "<div id='div" + i + "'><p></p></div><br />";
```

to

```
var divComposition = "<div id='div" + i + "'><p></p></div>";
```

Your code works on all versions of IE for me, and I had the JavaScript executing within the body of the HTML. You could throw all of your code in to a function and then call it from the body, if it still doesn't display properly.

Comment: right, I removed the line break. The black background still isn't there and even without the line breaks, in IE 8 it is inline but in IE 10 it is still not inline. For you, are the divs displayed inlnie (beside eachother) with a black background for IE 8 and IE 10? Also, my html, css and javascript are all already inside the body :/ .

Comment: Everything looks perfectly in IE10 on my end, using the exact same code. Try creating a completely new file with just your code snippets and a generic `for` loop and it should look fine.